# Any program to get my position in command line

Tags: linux, command-line, gps

Is it possible to get my location/position by any command line app?

I mean, my pc has internet connection and firewall is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've found some information on this website:

http://xmodulo.com/geographic-location-ip-address-command-line.html

Hope it's useful ;)

Comment: nope. Because it tells the city at the best.
And I want ~50-100m precision

Like in google maps :: Locate me feature